# Alternate constructor on Scala case class not defined: not enough arguments for method

Tags: scala

I can't figure out why this doesn't work... During compile I get the following error:

```
[error] /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server-2/project/glimpulse-server/app/service/GPGlimpleService.scala:17: not enough arguments for method apply: (id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long, attachments: List[models.GPAttachment])models.GPLayer in object GPLayer.
[error] Unspecified value parameter attachments.
[error]     private val layer1: List[GPLayer] = List(GPLayer(1, 42, 1, 9), GPLayer(2, 42, 2, 9))
```

For this case class... note the definition of an alternate constructor:

```
case class GPLayer(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long, attachments: List[GPAttachment]) {
    def this(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long) = this(id, glimpleId, layerOrder, created, List[GPAttachment]())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GPLayer(1, 42, 1, 9)
```

is the same as writing

```
GPLayer.apply(1, 42, 1, 9)
```

So instead of defining an alternative constructor, you should define an alternative `apply` method in the companion object `GPLayer`.

```
case class GPLayer(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long, attachments: List[GPAttachment]) 

object GPLayer {
  def apply(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long) = GPLayer(id, glimpleId, layerOrder, created, List[GPAttachment]())
}
```

If you want to call the altnernative constructor instead, you must add the `new`-keyword:

```
new GPLayer(1, 42, 1, 9)
```

---

**Edit:** As [Nicolas Cailloux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4659367/nicolas-cailloux) mentioned, your alternative constructor is really just providing a default value for the member `attachments`, so the best solution would actually be to not introduce a new method, but to specify this default value as follows:

```
case class GPLayer(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long, attachments: List[GPAttachment] = Nil)
```

Comment: Oh my. Talk about being blind to one's own code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your case, you could just provide a default value for the last argument :

```
case class GPLayer(id: Long, glimpleId: Long, layerOrder: Int, created: Long, attachments: List[GPAttachment] = List())
```

Comment: Since the code in the question is really just specifying a default argument, this is much cleaner than adding a further constructor / apply method. I incorporated this information (giving you credit) in my answer, but will remove it, if you don't like me taking part of your answer; if so, just add a comment @ my username so I'll get notified. In any case: Good addendum  +1

Comment: No problem, since your answer has more points and is more visible!